# RavenDB -Patch API: How do I fetch all the document IDs for a given Type in preparation for a large PatchCommand

Tags: api, patch, ravendb

RavenDB supports Patching via its [PatchAPI](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates). This is great but I am having a problem when I want to patching a large set.

**The Scenario**

- I have removed a property from my User entity
- I want to patch all existing Users to reflect this change
- The PatchAPI demands that I know in advance all of the User Ids
- Therefore I need to fetch all of the Ids of all of the Users
- But RavenDB imposes a limit on the number of items it returns
- This limit can be increased using the .Take(**x**) clause
- But I don't know the value of '**x**'
- So I guess and make **x** = *a-really-big-value* and all is well - right?

This guessing and hoping smells of fish to me so I strongly suspect I have missed something obvious.

**The Question**

How do I fetch the complete set of ids of a given type without fore-knowledge of the set-size ?

or

How do I patch a complete set based on the Type with no restrictions on the count.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RavenDB Set Based updates, see here for details:
http://ayende.com/blog/4535/set-based-operations-with-ravendb

Comment: Thanks. Set based approach certainly works. However I was hoping to use the standard LINQ syntax style to say the equivalent of 'GetAll', for when you have small sets that do not justify the set-based approach but never-the-less may, one day, have more than 255 members. Is the only way to account for future-set-growth to junk the standard syntax and go for the set-based approach?